# Cumulative sum in mysql view

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table holding values for each month of different years.

```
Entries:
entry_id
entry_date
entry_amount
```

Now I want a view which holds all entry values, and the cumulative sum of the current year's amounts.

```
Entries_sum_view:
entry_id
entry_date
entry_amount
entry_cumulative_yearly_sum
```

where entry_cumulative_yearly_sum = SUM(all entries from Jan 01 of YEAR(entry_date) up to entry_date)

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution:

```
SELECT e1.*, SUM(e2.entry_amount) AS cum_sum 
FROM Entry e1, Entry e2
WHERE 
  e2.account_idfk = e1.account_idfk AND
  e2.entry_period_end_date BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(e1.entry_period_end_date),1) AND e1.entry_period_end_date GROUP BY e1.entry_id
```